# Trouble setting the size of photos on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

my friends have a problem. I do not understand a few days ago where the problem is.

I began to change my software photos in standard sizes and in the following folders.

drawable

drawable-hdpi

drawable-mdpi

drawable-xhdpi

drawable-xxhdpi

drawable-xxxhdpi

With similar names and different sizes (all of which I know and know in names and folders I do not have a problem with)

And even to make sure the layers were in different sizes in the following folders, I set it up and set it up.

layout-larg

layout-normal

layout-smal

layout-xlarg

But at runtime, it does not select the right size according to the size of the phone

That is, in any case, it uses a small photo.
Both in large size devices and small size devices.

If you need to automatically select the right photo from the appropriate folder based on the size you want.
Where is the problem in your opinion?
I translated the text with Google Translator, I hope you understand what I said.

Comment: the images of each size if they are the right size? because even if they are in different folders it is important that the image has the right size for each resolution.

Comment: Yes, I got the screenshots with Illustrator, which has the ability to get the standard output from the standard Android site.
For example, a photo that we output will take the size of 0.75X-1.0X-2.0X-3.0X and 4.0X out of the output.
With these conditions I do not know why the images do not apply on app.

Comment: could you share some XML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried .svg images this can save you a lot of space and you don't need to store several images with different sizes only one .svg image is needed for different screen sizes the quality of the image wont be lost based on devices. https://www.lifewire.com/svg-file-4120603